# opencart issue of displaing product on home page

Tags: opencart, product, opencart2.x

I've been searching around on Google to find an accurate tutorial that explains how to display products on the home page but so far nothing is working!

I'm using opencart 2.x and I need to add product on homepage but nothing work. If someone knows how to add categories product on homepage please reply

Comment: Your need display of all poducts on home page ?

Comment: No. I need to display from Individual category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a module for it.

Go to the link below

[Show products of Category OpenCart 2 module for free](https://webocreation.com/blog/show-products-of-category-opencart-2-module-for-free)
Download the modules and set the modules which will show products of the chosen category at admin.

Go through the description in the blog above to get details how to set it up.